# Automatically handling disposing of unsafe allocated memory in Swift

Tags: swift, memory-management, unsafe-pointers

In a Swift program that interacts with low level operating system functions, I allocate "Unsafe" memory blocks in order to buffer data.  These blocks are stored in a `struct` that can be passed around various parts of the program.  How can I track these copies and ensure the memory block is deallocated once all the copies are finished with?

Example code:

```
struct Packet {
    var memoryBlock : UnsafeRawPointer
    init () {
        let block = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate (bytes: 128, alignedTo: 4)
        someProcessThatFillsTheBuffer (block); 
        memoryBlock = UnsafeRawPointer(block);
    }
}

let packet = Packet()
process1.handle (packet); process2.handle (packet)
```

How can I ensure the allocated block is disposed of once both process1 and process2 have finished with it?

In C++, I'd use a `shared_ptr` to track the allocation.  Does Swift have something similar I can use for this?  Some way of using the existing ARC system to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `class` instead and release the memory in `deinit`:

```
class Packet {
    var memoryBlock : UnsafeRawPointer
    init() {
        let block = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate(byteCount: 128, alignment: 4)
        //someProcessThatFillsTheBuffer (block);
        memoryBlock = UnsafeRawPointer(block);
    }

    deinit {
        memoryBlock.deallocate()
    }
}
```

Now instances of `Packet` are *references* to an object and can be 
passed around. ARC (automatic reference counting) ensures that `deinit` is called when the last reference to the
object is gone.